# Como usar o Localization do Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estou com um dúvida para utilizar o Localization do Laravel corretamente, tenho uma aplicação em Português e tenho que traduzi-lá para inglês..minha dúvida é a seguinte ex:

```
<h2>Isso será apenas um teste não fique bravo</h2>
```

Criei um arquivo tradutor.php dentro da pasta resources/lang/en/tradutor.php, que possui o seguinte código:

```
    <?php 

    return [



    //**dúvida aqui**   Na documentação pede para criar um array com a palavra original sendo a chave e a tradução sendo o valor ex:

'apenas' => 'only' 




    ]

     ?>
```

Como eu tenho essa frase contida no h2, tenho que traduzir palavra por palavra ou tenho que traduzir a frase inteira de uma vez só ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arquivos de internacionalização ou localization independente da linguagem traduz **apenas** o que você previamente configurar... Você até poderia traduzir palavra por palavra da frase, porém o *output* não teria qualidade pois não faria sentido.

Respondendo sua pergunta, você deve sim escrever a frase por completo:

```
<?php 
    return [
'apenas' => 'only',
'Isso será apenas um teste não fique bravo' => 'This will only be a test. Do not be mad.' 
]

 ?>
```

Para frases que você não sabe se vai ou não existir eu recomendo utilizar API's de tradução pois não vale a pena você desenvolver algo pois para ter um bom resultado teria que aplicar machine learning o que custaria muito mais do que utilizar algo feito por empresas gigantes que já utilizam dessa tecnologia.

[Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/) (Eles dão R$ 900,00 para você testar as ferramentas de cloud da pra utilizar o tradutor por 1 ano de boa)

[AWS Translate](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/translate/) (Até 2 Milhões de caracteres de graça por mês durante 1 ano)

[Microsoft Translator](https://translator.microsoft.com/) (Até 2 Milhões de caracteres de graça por mês durante 1 ano)